# Can't search for deleted questions in favorites with 10K+ reputation

Tags: support, deleted-questions, bookmarks

I was attempting to rifle through my favorites one day to find an old question I had wanted to share with an old colleague.  In doing this, I attempted to search through known keywords that I had, but to no avail.

(Turns out the question wasn't favorited by me.  Whoops.)

In realizing this, I discovered that I actually can't search questions which are deleted in my favorites.

As an example:

[image]

I kept that question around for reasons.  Reasons that I honestly can't remember now.

Here's what I get when attempting to search for it:

[image]

Is this *likely* due to the case that I can't search for deleted questions on the site that I don't own?  If so, could this be somehow ameliorated - if I can't search the deleted favorite, then remove it from my favorites?

Comment: Why would you want it removed from your favorites? That's just further limiting your ability to find the question.

Comment: @Cai I can't search for them using the readily available tooling. I'd have to roll my own tools to use them.  It was an option; I really don't want to lose some deleted favorites.

Comment: You can use your browsers search function, or script your own solution. I just don't see the logic in removing it from your favorites.

Comment: @Cai:  My initial thought is that it's a bit strange to dangle the deleted questions in my favorites but not allow me to search them.  I can respect that you shouldn't be able to really find deleted content that doesn't belong to you, but in my mind there's not much harm that can come from allowing me to search the favorites I already have registered.

Answer (score 4):

> Is this likely due to the case that I can't search for deleted questions on the site

That's correct. We can't search for deleted content, except for a our own questions and answers, by adding `deleted:1` operator. (10k only privilege)

Having the deleted question still appear in our favorites list is kind of a "bonus" in my opinion, and better not be removed. It's easy enough to search the list by browser search, going over the pages.

In extreme cases of thousands of favorites, userscript can be created to search them all easily via client side scripting. (or just get all the deleted questions, as you can already search in the rest.)